# AWS amazon web services database and www instance resizing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working on an eCommerce website (developed and set up by other develpers) that have the web server on a m4.2xlarge instance and the database on a t2.micro (EC2 and EBS instances).
The usual traffic is about 5,000 unique visitors/day but we are expecting a huge increment in the nex future because of some advertising on big newspapers and I would like to understand if I need to scale up the web server instance or the DB instance or both.
It is not clear to me if the two instances are sharing the same RAM and CPU or if they are completely separated.
Thank you !

Comment: are you sure the production db is on a t2.micro? it looks a bit small next to the m4.2xlarge. Do you use autoscaling?

Comment: Hi, yes I am and sounds strange to me too. I have double checked and the autoscaling is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the systems will have different CPU and RAM.

You should choose RDS instead of a normal EC2 instance for Database.

You can take a backup from older instance and load into your RDS instances. This will also help you maintaining high availability as well.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I noticed that the CPU utilization for the DB instance is around 1%, and this leave me a little bit confused because on the www instance that is much more bigger it is around 50%. Is there a way to check the RAM usage in AWS instead of using the TOP linux command?

Comment: `top` would give the most accurate metrics. It sounds like your application doesn't actually use the database very much.